# Alternative to assign function in r

Tags: r, loops, assign, dynamic-variables

I am using the following code in a loop, I am just replicating the part which I am facing the problem in. The entire code is extremely long and I have removed parts which are running fine in between these lines. This is just to explain the problem:

```
    for (j in 1:2)
     {
      assign(paste("numeric_data",j,sep="_"),unique_id)
      for (i in 1:2)
      {
       assign(paste("numeric_data",j,sep="_"), 
              merge(eval(as.symbol(paste("numeric_data",j,sep="_"))),
              eval(as.symbol(paste("sd_1",i,sep="_"))),all.x = TRUE))
       }
      }
```

The problem that I am facing is that instead of assign in the second step, I want to use (eval+paste)

```
    for (j in 1:2)
     {
      assign(paste("numeric_data",j,sep="_"),unique_id)
      for (i in 1:2)
      {
       eval(as.symbol((paste("numeric_data",j,sep="_"))))<- 
              merge(eval(as.symbol(paste("numeric_data",j,sep="_"))),
              eval(as.symbol(paste("sd_1",i,sep="_"))),all.x = TRUE)
       }
      }
```

However R does not accept eval while assigning new variables. I looked at the forum and everywhere assign is suggested to solve the problem. However, if I use assign the loop overwrites my previously generated "numeric_data" instead of adding to it, hence I get output for only one value of i instead of both.

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider the use of `eval` "normal".

Comment: Sure, let me remove that remark

Comment: You don't have to remove it; what I meant was, why do you want to use `eval` specifically?

Comment: ...nor is the casual use of `assign` "normal". Named lists! Named lists! Named lists! (Picture me jumping up and down like a big doofus waving my arms about.)

Comment: hmm.. I am not very good with programming. Mostly I google solutions. Can you direct me to a post where I can find a solution to this. I could find an answer to this on stackoverflow..

Comment: Please explain what your overall goal is.

Comment: I think that a major difficulty with this question is that is formulated as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @nrussell - The goal is to create a dataset that I can merge with itself and subsequent dataset. For instance, I have ds1 (which to begin with just has IDs), which I merge with ds2 (ds2 has IDs and some variables - the output from the merge is still called ds1), then I merge ds1 (new output) again with ds3 (which has IDs and some other variables), the resulting output is again called ds1. If I use assign, ds1 switches back to original form while merging with ds3 (hence overwriting the merge with ds2 instead of adding to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic intro to one of the most fundamental data structures in R. I highly recommend reading more about them in standard documentation sources.

```
#A list is a (possible named) set of objects
numeric_data <- list(A1 = 1, A2 = 2)
#I can refer to elements by name or by position, e.g. numeric_data[[1]]
> numeric_data[["A1"]]
[1] 1

#I can add elements to a list with a particular name 
> numeric_data <- list()
> numeric_data[["A1"]] <- 1
> numeric_data[["A2"]] <- 2
> numeric_data
$A1
[1] 1

$A2
[1] 2

#I can refer to named elements by building the name with paste() 
> numeric_data[[paste0("A",1)]]
[1] 1

#I can change all the names at once... 
> numeric_data <- setNames(numeric_data,paste0("B",1:2))
> numeric_data
$B1
[1] 1

$B2
[1] 2

#...in multiple ways 
> names(numeric_data) <- paste0("C",1:2)
> numeric_data
$C1
[1] 1

$C2
[1] 2
```

Basically, the lesson is that if you have objects with names with numeric suffixes: `object_1`, `object_2`, etc. they should almost *always* be elements in a single list with names that you can easily construct and refer to.

Comment: I picture you jumping :D +1 although this probably doesn't answer the OP's question. But I guess it points in the right direction.

Comment: @RHertel Figuring out a way to help people who have coded themselves into this particular corner has been a constant puzzle for me. I've tried answering many different ways, but probably the only real way to help would be to sit at the keyboard with them and look at the whole code together.

Comment: It didn't answer my question, but it give me a different idea to approach the problem